# Amanzon SNS unconfirmed subscription are removed from the SNS Topic after few days

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a SNS Topic then I created multiple email subscribers to that SNS Topic, after few days(2) the subscriptions that were not confirmed were removed from my Topic, is this a normal behavior or is there some expiration that are set on unconfirmed SNS Topic subscriptions?

I created my email subscriptions using the AWS management console and there was no settings for expiration when I created them.

I created my SNS Topic and added email subscription to it but after few days(2) the subscriptions that had an unconfirmed status were removed from my SNS Topic subscriptions list, the people that tried to confirm afterwards got and error message saying "subscription not found".

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-sns-automatic-deletion-unconfirmed-subscriptions/ - 2 days seems to be correct.

Comment: Also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-delete-subscription-topic.html

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SNS automatically deletes unconfirmed subscriptions after 48 hours. This applies to all new subscriptions, and can not be modified. The timeframe used to be 72 hours, but [has recently been reduced to 48 hours](https://go.aws/3OqYOE5).